# Joint pdf, mean of Y and X

Tags: probability, statistics

X and Y have a joint pdf $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \frac{1}{y} , 0 <x < y, 0<y<1$.

The random variables X and Y are independent, right?

Also, how would I go about finding $\mu_X=E(X)$ and $\mu_Y=E(Y)$?

Comment: First find the marginal distributions of X and Y. And then you can find E(X) and E(Y) in the usual way.